# How to install plugins in geany while in windows operating system

Tags: c++, autocomplete

I am a aspiring competetive programmer and I have found geany to be a great C++ editor. But I doesn't have the Autobracet plugin. Anybone please help to to find a way to install plugin for geany while in windows os?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Geany-Plugins bundle for Windows on https://plugins.geany.org/downloads.html. The installer includes the [Autoclose](https://plugins.geany.org/autoclose.html) plugin which is probably what you are looking for.

Be sure to download the installer of the same version as Geany.

After you have installed the plugin, open Geany and then `Tools`>`Plugin Manager` and enable the `Autoclose` plugin.